# SQL index for fuzzy query

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Hi I am using Ruby on Rails and I am finding records 'near' a specific location.

```
def self.around(lat, long)
    where('lat >= ?', lat - 1).where('lat <= ?', lat + 1).
      where('long >= ?', long - 1).where('long <= ?', long + 1)
end
```

The ruby code above is not important. But it creates a sql query:

```
SELECT "examples"."id", "examples"."name", "examples"."long", "examples"."lat", 
       "examples"."status", "examples"."icon_url" 
FROM "examples" 
WHERE (lat >= 49.23332013941735) AND (lat <= 51.23332013941735) 
  AND (long >= -136.74148535063478) AND (long <= -134.74148535063478) 
  AND "examples"."car_id" IS NULL
```

Even if there are no 'examples' to be returned this query takes 105ms.
Usually I have queries in the 25ms, so I wonder if there is a way to index this.

Comment: Which indexes do you already have?

Comment: PostGIS? K-NN indexes?

Comment: the KNN looks promising, but  have not tried it out yet. From the example it seems just to searching by it, but is there any index that is needed that I do not know about.